# Cypress get() best practice and performance question

Tags: cypress

When creating a cypress test I'm using the get function to retrieve DOM elements.
I saw that in the documentation they write that the best practice is to use data-test attribute, but performance-wise, what will be better to use:

```
cy.get(`div[data-testid*=${testid}]`)
```

or

```
cy.get('[data-testid=${testid}]')
```

If im adding the element type, will it be better for performance?

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it makes that big of a difference, but in the documentation all the examples use

```
cy.get('[data-testid=${testid}]')
```

See here for more best practices

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices